# PySide/PyQt: 'TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable' when trying to use 'currentItemChanged' with QTableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a table with some data that I want to be able to edit through the `QTableWidget`. Upon trying to connect the `currentItemChanged` signal:

```
self.QTableWidget.currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem,QTableWidgetItem).connect(self.editCell)
```

I get the following error:

```
'TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable'
```

I went looking in to the `QtDesigner`, where you can connect signals. I made a `QTableWidget`, and connected it to a label so that changing the `currentItem` hid the label.

In the signal connecting dialog the `currentItemChanged` signal was written thus:

```
currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*,QTableWidgetItem*)
```

I don't know what the `*` means, but I assume it's important.

Am I using the wrong signal or is my syntax wrong somehow? In short, I want there a signal to be emitted upon changing any particular item/cell(I'm not sure what the distinction is)

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*EDIT****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

EDIT: In the QTableWidgetItem class documentation I also found that it has functions column() and row().

I tried adding them like this:

```
self.QTableWidget.currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem.column(QTableWidgetItem.column()),QTableWidgetItem.row()).connect(self.editCell)
```

But got the error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'column' requires a 'PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem' object but received a 'Shiboken.ObjectType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit is concerning:

```
self.QTableWidget
```

If your table is literally called "QTableWidget" there may be confusion later on. Specifically, the error you are getting makes it look like you are calling `QTableWidget.currentItemChanged`.

Also, its worth reviewing the PyQT documentation on ["new-style signals", specifically on dealing with overloads](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) to understand how it all works. Fortunately however, [`QTableWidget.currentItemChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#currentItemChanged) isn't overloaded so, the code you should be using should just be:

```
self.yourTable.currentItemChanged.connect(self.editCell)
```

Regarding your later edits, in this code:

```
currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*,QTableWidgetItem*)
```

The `QTableWidgetItem`s that are being parsed are arguments that are given to the signal. You can't change them, as they are definined in the method that defines the slot, and passed when the signal is fired. From the documentation linked above:

> **void currentItemChanged (QTableWidgetItem *,QTableWidgetItem *)**
>
> This signal is emitted whenever the current item changes. The previous item is the item that previously had the focus, current is the new current item.

Comment: No, QTableWidget isn't the name of my table, I just thought it would make it more clear. In retrospect, I don't know how I thought that. Thanks, your suggestion worked, however it seem that I misunderstood what was meant by 'currentItemChanged'. I thought it meant edited. Should read the docs more carefully.